# div contents overwrite each other

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, css

I have a div in which I applied text and images.It looks fine until I convert it as an image using html2canvs library.When this div is converted to image the text become smaller and other image inside div overwrite it. I want that the div image looks as it was before capturing that div.

```js
function ConvertToImage(btnExport) {
  html2canvas($("#myDIV")[0]).then(function(canvas) {
    var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
    $("[id*=hfImageData]").val(base64);
    __doPostBack(btnExport.name, "");
  });
  return false;
}
```

```css
#myDIV {
  width: 550px;
  height: 650px;
  background-image: url(myimg.png);
  color: orange;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 150px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 2px solid midnightblue;
  margin-right: 150px;
  font-size: x-large;
}
#logo {
  width: 85px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url('logo.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
#logo2 {
  width: 85px;
  height: 150px;
  background-image: url('logo2.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.text_decoration {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDIV">
  <div style="height:510px;width:290px;margin:50px 100px">
    <input maxlength="15" type="text" id="myText" class="text_decoration resize-drag" autocomplete="off" />
    <div id="logo" class="resize-drag"></div>
    <div id="logo2" class="resize-drag"></div>
    <img id="images" src="#" class="resize-drag" style="display:none" />
  </div>
</div>

<asp:HiddenField ID="hfImageData" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="btnExport" Text="Export to Image" runat="server" UseSubmitBehavior="false" 
 OnClick="ExportToImage" OnClientClick="return ConvertToImage(this)" CssClass="btnstyle" Height="50px" Width="200px" />
```

```
       protected void ExportToImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string base64 = Request.Form[hfImageData.UniqueID].Split(',')[1];
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
        MemoryStream msImage = new MemoryStream(bytes,0,bytes.Length);
        msImage.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        System.Drawing.Image imageTosave = 
        System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(msImage, true);
        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + ".png";
        string filePath = 
        Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/CanvasImages/"+fileName));         
        imageTosave.Save(filePath, ImageFormat.Png);
        string dbPath = "~/CanvasImages/" +fileName;
       }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - please show us what you've done through code, what your expected outcome is, and the issue you're having! We'd be happy to help otherwise!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] with code so that we can actually see what you're doing.

Comment: I updated my question please review it. Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: WHAT button?  seems central to the question here.  How do you call your function?  "a textbox is appeared" - do you mean shown? if so HOW? please add more code, markup and details to your question, make the sample actually produce the invalid behavior you observe.  You have `html2canvas` in your code, put an actual reference to that in your sample.  Be complete but concise.

Comment: Your CSS has width of 85, 85, and 200 on elements yet they are inside and element with only 290 with with a margin top 50 and right of 100px.  Your numbers do not seem to add up.  Putting style in markup AND css nearly always gets a mess started, use CSS only.

Comment: Update your question so it actually shows the issue, what is happening - including the buttons, JavaScript, Libraries etc.  THEN clearly and as short of description as possible describe your desired behavior instead.

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss I checked it and i found that margin and height/width create problems but these are also necessary to write. What should I do? Thank you

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss I updated it please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert however when I have this issue I find that the most common issues are

```
display: block;
```

or Padding and Margins